# How to get only one object from ManyToOne table, instead of queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Table Images:

```
id| image   | item_id
15|some/path|   45
16|some/path|   45
17|some/path|   45
```

**First try:**

```
recommended_items = Item.objects.all().filter(rating__gte=9) // All my items (`item_id` column)

for item in recommended_items :
    image = Images.objects.get(item_id=item.id)[:1]
```

It works for first item with `id=45` but for the rest it returns **error**:

> Images matching query does not exist.

**Second try:**

```
for item in recommended_items :
    image = Images.objects.filter(item=item)[:1]
```

Now it works for all items, existing or not, but it returns iterate object and I should add for loop for just one object, like this:

```
for i in image:
    print(i.image)
```

What is the right way to handle this ? I want just one record (the last one if it is possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use `last()` method as below...

```
image = Images.objects.filter(item=item).last()
```

For first use `first()` method...

```
image = Images.objects.filter(item=item).first()
```

Comment: This is solution only for the last part of problem.

Comment: @DimiturDimitrov What is the remaining problem?  `last` / `first` method will return `None` if no object exists.  You can check `if image is None` to account for this case

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use index of element?

```
for item in recommended_items :
    image = Images.objects.filter(item=item)[0]
```

Comment: It will throw an error if item doesn't exist, like item with id 46 for example.